# Solid of revolution simulator?

Tags: software, functions, graphing

I'm searching for an offline portable program that demonstrates the concept of how does a function revolve around X or Y axis It should be similar to this: [Solid of revolution simulator](http://www.shodor.org/interactivate/activities/FunctionRevolution/)

but I want to use it in a place that has no WiFi connection so if any one knows a similar program or maybe how to extract the program from the website I'd be very thankful.

Comment: Cell phones don't work either?

Comment: Cell phones work but with no internet access

Answer (score 2):

Calcplot3d might be a good choice:

http://web.monroecc.edu/calcNSF/

Comment: This is good thank you, but I want the programs to show to process of the fucntion revolve around any axis like a slow motion plotting of how it goes, is that possible

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you would find this on GeoGebra.org

You can download the software and any community produced .ggb file for offline use, and there's thousands of ready-made interactives. You can even compile them into an ebook with notes and exercises.

Comment: For example: https://www.geogebra.org/material/show/id/286177

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed Mathematica or  "CDF Player" on your machine, you can download and use these demonstration while offline: [1](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SolidOfRevolution/) [2](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SolidsOfRevolution/)

Comment: That's good, but I would prefer to input my own function is that possible?